# Request to Flask Application Does Not Get Through to Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I have written a «Hello World» application using Python (3.7.4) and Flask (`hello.py`):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I use the following versions of Flask and gunicorn (`requirements.txt`):

```
Flask==1.1.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
```

Which I install as follows:

```
$ sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Since I'm running the example on Arch Linux, `pip` is actually `pip3`.

When I start the application:

```
$ gunicorn hello:app
```

The application works as expected:

```
$ curl localhost:8000
Hello, World!
```

Now I want to run it using Docker (Version 19.03.3-ce), for which I have written this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7.4

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY hello.py /app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "hello:app", "--log-file=-"]
```

I build the image and run the container with a shell script (`run.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

docker build . -t flaskdemo
docker run -it --rm --name flaskdemoapp -p 8000:8000 flaskdemo
```

Which works as expected:

```
$ ./run.sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  66.05kB
Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.7.4
 ---> 9fa56d0addae
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 81a38303aabd
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a73abfac4cdf
Step 4/8 : COPY requirements.txt /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e7507f42bbae
Step 5/8 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 06c4adb1310b
Step 6/8 : COPY hello.py /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fa5d374f6c93
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> df5e0d5ada7d
Step 8/8 : CMD ["gunicorn", "hello:app", "--log-file=-"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 08babb3f604a
Successfully built 08babb3f604a
Successfully tagged flaskdemo:latest
[2019-10-19 13:09:43 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-10-19 13:09:43 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1)
[2019-10-19 13:09:43 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-10-19 13:09:43 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
```

Unfortunately, the request does not come through to the container:

```
$ curl localhost:8000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

There is no additional log line from the container.

Docker works fine on my machine in general. For example, when I run `httpd`:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:80 httpd
```

I get a response to my request:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

So I guess there must be something wrong with my `Dockerfile` or the way I run the container.

PS: Feel free to clone the code from [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/patrickbucher/flaskdemoapp.git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM python:3.7.4
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app"]
```

Then run with:

```
docker build --tag flask_gunicorn_app .
docker run --detach -p 80:8000 flask_gunicorn_app
```

Comment: Almost: `hello:app` was correct, but the `-b 0.0.0.0:8000` did the trick!
But `-p 80:8000` is not a good idea, I think.